# How can I read in characters with getchar() without the newline?

Tags: arrays, c, file-io, char, newline

I need to read in a very long string of characters from stdin with getchar(), but I need it to not have the newlines that are currently included in the file.

I'm not married to getchar(), so if there's a better way, please let me know.

Here is a small version of my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>


#define MAX 4000


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  int c;
  int i = 0;
  char sequence[MAX];

  while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
  {
    sequence[i] = c;
    i++;
  }


  printf("%s", sequence);

}
```

**This is my input file, which currently resembles the output of the program, meaning it prints exactly as it was read into the array, like this:**

```
MFVFLVLLPLVSSQCVNLTTRTQLPPAYTNSFTRGVYYPDKVFRSSVLHSTQDLFLPFFS
NVTWFHAIHVSGTNGTKRFDNPVLPFNDGVYFASTEKSNIIRGWIFGTTLDSKTQSLLIV
NNATNVVIKVCEFQFCNDPFLGVYYHKNNKSWMESEFRVYSSANNCTFEYVSQPFLMDLE
GKQGNFKNLREFVFKNIDGYFKIYSKHTPINLVRDLPQGFSALEPLVDLPIGINITRFQT
LLALHRSYLTPGDSSSGWTAGAAAYYVGYLQPRTFLLKYNENGTITDAVDCALDPLSETK
CTLKSFTVEKGIYQTSNFRVQPTESIVRFPNITNLCPFGEVFNATRFASVYAWNRKRISN
CVADYSVLYNSASFSTFKCYGVSPTKLNDLCFTNVYADSFVIRGDEVRQIAPGQTGKIAD
YNYKLPDDFTGCVIAWNSNNLDSKVGGNYNYLYRLFRKSNLKPFERDISTEIYQAGSTPC
NGVEGFNCYFPLQSYGFQPTNGVGYQPYRVVVLSFELLHAPATVCGPKKSTNLVKNKCVN
FNFNGLTGTGVLTESNKKFLPFQQFGRDIADTTDAVRDPQTLEILDITPCSFGGVSVITP
GTNTSNQVAVLYQDVNCTEVPVAIHADQLTPTWRVYSTGSNVFQTRAGCLIGAEHVNNSY
ECDIPIGAGICASYQTQTNSPRRARSVASQSIIAYTMSLGAENSVAYSNNSIAIPTNFTI
SVTTEILPVSMTKTSVDCTMYICGDSTECSNLLLQYGSFCTQLNRALTGIAVEQDKNTQE
VFAQVKQIYKTPPIKDFGGFNFSQILPDPSKPSKRSFIEDLLFNKVTLADAGFIKQYGDC
LGDIAARDLICAQKFNGLTVLPPLLTDEMIAQYTSALLAGTITSGWTFGAGAALQIPFAM
QMAYRFNGIGVTQNVLYENQKLIANQFNSAIGKIQDSLSSTASALGKLQDVVNQNAQALN
TLVKQLSSNFGAISSVLNDILSRLDKVEAEVQIDRLITGRLQSLQTYVTQQLIRAAEIRA
SANLAATKMSECVLGQSKRVDFCGKGYHLMSFPQSAPHGVVFLHVTYVPAQEKNFTTAPA
ICHDGKAHFPREGVFVSNGTHWFVTQRNFYEPQIITTDNTFVSGNCDVVIGIVNNTVYDP
LQPELDSFKEELDKYFKNHTSPDVDLGDISGINASVVNIQKEIDRLNEVAKNLNESLIDL
QELGKYEQYIKWPWYIWLGFIAGLIAIVMVTIMLCCMTSCCSCLKGCCSCGSCCKFDEDD
SEPVLKGVKLHYT
```

**I need this to be stored in this char array without newlines, but the following addition to my program doesn't work:**

```
#include <stdio.h>


#define MAX 4000


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  int c;
  int i = 0;
  char sequence[MAX];

  while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
  {
    if(c == '\n') // START OF ADDITION
    {
      continue;
    }
    else
    {
      sequence[i] = c;
      i++;
    } // END OF ADDITION
  }


  printf("%s", sequence);

}
```

The output of this is the following, which is the last line PLUS the remainder of the line directly above it:

```
SEPVLKGVKLHYTWYIWLGFIAGLIAIVMVTIMLCCMTSCCSCLKGCCSCGSCCKFDEDD
```

Essentially, what I need is this:

```
MFVFLVLLPLVSSQCVNLTTRTQLPPAYTNSFTRGVYYPDKVFRSSVLHSTQDLFLPFFSNVTWFHAIHVSGTNGTKRFDNPVLPFNDGVYFASTEKSNIIRGWIFGTTLDSKTQSLLIVNNATNVVIKVCEFQFCNDPFLGVYYHKNNKSWMESEFRVYSSANNCTFEYVSQPFLMDLEGKQGNFKNLREFVFKNIDGYFKIYSKHTPINLVRDLPQGFSALEPLVDLPIGINITRFQTLLALHRSYLTPGDSSSGWTAGAAAYYVGYLQPRTFLLKYNENGTITDAVDCALDPLSETKCTLKSFTVEKGIYQTSNFRVQPTESIVRFPNITNLCPFGEVFNATRFASVYAWNRKRISNCVADYSVLYNSASFSTFKCYGVSPTKLNDLCFTNVYADSFVIRGDEVRQIAPGQTGKIADYNYKLPDDFTGCVIAWNSNNLDSKVGGNYNYLYRLFRKSNLKPFERDISTEIYQAGSTPCNGVEGFNCYFPLQSYGFQPTNGVGYQPYRVVVLSFELLHAPATVCGPKKSTNLVKNKCVNFNFNGLTGTGVLTESNKKFLPFQQFGRDIADTTDAVRDPQTLEILDITPCSFGGVSVITPGTNTSNQVAVLYQDVNCTEVPVAIHADQLTPTWRVYSTGSNVFQTRAGCLIGAEHVNNSYECDIPIGAGICASYQTQTNSPRRARSVASQSIIAYTMSLGAENSVAYSNNSIAIPTNFTISVTTEILPVSMTKTSVDCTMYICGDSTECSNLLLQYGSFCTQLNRALTGIAVEQDKNTQEVFAQVKQIYKTPPIKDFGGFNFSQILPDPSKPSKRSFIEDLLFNKVTLADAGFIKQYGDCLGDIAARDLICAQKFNGLTVLPPLLTDEMIAQYTSALLAGTITSGWTFGAGAALQIPFAMQMAYRFNGIGVTQNVLYENQKLIANQFNSAIGKIQDSLSSTASALGKLQDVVNQNAQALNTLVKQLSSNFGAISSVLNDILSRLDKVEAEVQIDRLITGRLQSLQTYVTQQLIRAAEIRASANLAATKMSECVLGQSKRVDFCGKGYHLMSFPQSAPHGVVFLHVTYVPAQEKNFTTAPAICHDGKAHFPREGVFVSNGTHWFVTQRNFYEPQIITTDNTFVSGNCDVVIGIVNNTVYDPLQPELDSFKEELDKYFKNHTSPDVDLGDISGINASVVNIQKEIDRLNEVAKNLNESLIDLQELGKYEQYIKWPWYIWLGFIAGLIAIVMVTIMLCCMTSCCSCLKGCCSCGSCCKFDEDDSEPVLKGVKLHYT
```

The reason I need it this way is because later on, I have to count through this array with arguments given by the user but it's currently not working as intended because I have extra characters due to the newline characters. So if given the command to return the position at 501, it actually returns the position at 509, because there are eight line breaks before it reaches that position, thus adding eight characters and returning the wrong value.

**The program is run like this**

```
gcc main.c -o m.exe

m.exe < test.in
```

If anyone has any ideas let me know. Thank you!

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/04Roc1IyIFSJwILk). The cause may be the *undefined behavior* invoked by passing an array that is not null-terminated for `%s` and using value of non-initialized non-static local variable.

Comment: Don't forget to write `sequence[i] = '\0';` after the loop.

Comment: Simple `0` will do

Comment: It looks like the `i` is accidentally initialized to zero for some reason when newline character is entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're seeing just "the last line plus the remainder of the line above it", the most likely explanation is that you have CRNL line endings in the file, and you're (just) getting rid of the newlines and leaving the CR characters.  Change your ignore test to:

```
if (c == '\n' || c == '\r') continue;
```

or just

```
if (isspace(c)) continue;
```

and things should look better.

Comment: Yes, this worked. I didn't realize there was another type of line ending. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Simply ignore newlines and add null character at the end if you want to use this table as C string.

```
  while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
  {
    if(c == '\n') continue;
    sequence[i] = c;
    i++;
  }
  sequence[i] = 0;
```

Comment: Okay so this has me confused, because that's what I thought I was doing but when I remove my else statement from my second program example, I have what you have here. The 'else' is causing a problem, I don't know why.

Comment: @WhozCraig it was the else, I just got it to work by removing the else. I'm not sure why that's the case

Comment: Add terminating null character as you print it as C string. Both will work

Comment: @bannedfromquestioning it's not the else. That thing is superfluous and pointless. it's the missing terminator if anything.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeah you were right it's not the else, it still doesn't work though. The answer below is working for me, adding a condition for '\r' as well.